# Entity Framework - Setting up multiple table relations

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, rest

i'm unable to figure out how to set a correct relationship between 3 tables.
I'm working in a code-first approach.
This are my tables:

```
  public class Parkings
        {
            [Key]
            public int ParkId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string EndDate { get; set; }

            public int CityId { get; set; }

            public int StreetId { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("CityId")]
            public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }

        }


        public class Cities
        {
            [Key]
            public int CityId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string CityDesc { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Streets> Streets { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Parkings> Parkings { get; set; }
        }

        public class Streets
        {
            [Key]
            public int StreetId { get; set; }

            public int CityId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string StreetDesc { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("CityId")]
            public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }



        }
```

First i want to seed the database in my code, so it won't be empty.
I do it like that:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            //
            context.Cities.Add(
        new Cities() { CityId = 1, CityDesc = "Tel Aviv" }
        );
            context.Cities.Add(
    new Cities() { CityId = 2, CityDesc = "Ramat Gan" }

    );

            context.Streets.Add(
                new Streets() { StreetId = 1, CityId = 1, StreetDesc = "Pinkas"}
                );

            context.Streets.Add(
              new Streets() { StreetId = 2, CityId = 2, StreetDesc = "Bialik" }
              );

            context.Streets.Add(
              new Streets() { StreetId = 3, CityId = 1, StreetDesc = "Dizengoff" }
              );

            context.Parkings.Add(
              new Parkings() { StreetId = 1, CityId = 1, StartDate = "2018-01-17", EndDate = "2018-01-17" }
              );

            context.Parkings.Add(
          new Parkings() { StreetId = 3, CityId = 1, StartDate = "2019-01-17", EndDate = "2019-01-17" }
          );

            context.Parkings.Add(
         new Parkings() { StreetId = 2, CityId = 2, StartDate = "2018-01-17", EndDate = "2018-01-17" }
         );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

When i'm doing a get request to see the database, this is my result:

```
 {
    "cityId": 1,
    "cityDesc": "Tel Aviv",
    "streets": [
      {
        "streetId": 1,
        "streetDesc": "Pinkas",
        "parkings": [
          {
            "parkId": 1,
            "startDate": "2018-01-17",
            "endDate": "2018-01-17"
          },
          {
            "parkId": 2,
            "startDate": "2019-01-17",
            "endDate": "2019-01-17"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "streetId": 3,
        "streetDesc": "Dizengoff",
        "parkings": [
          {
            "parkId": 1,
            "startDate": "2018-01-17",
            "endDate": "2018-01-17"
          },
          {
            "parkId": 2,
            "startDate": "2019-01-17",
            "endDate": "2019-01-17"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "cityId": 2,
    "cityDesc": "Ramat Gan",
    "streets": [
      {
        "streetId": 2,
        "streetDesc": "Bialik",
        "parkings": [
          {
            "parkId": 3,
            "startDate": "2018-01-17",
            "endDate": "2018-01-17"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, CityId is working correctly, it assigns the parking to the correct city, but it ignores the StreetId, so the parking get duplicated in the target city.

How should i configure it, so it will work with both CityId & StreetId?
Any test i'm doing is not giving the right result..

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You have `StreetId` in your `Parkings` class, but there is no navigation property for `Street` in it. Why? For `CityId` you did it. I'm assuming that your structure (3 tables) not correct, it is not corresponds with your json. `City` have a collection of `Street`s, each `Street` have a collection of `Parking`

Comment: Hey @HemidAbbasov, well i  tried to add `[ForeignKey("StreetId")]
            public virtual Streets Streets { get; set; }` , but i get an error on duplicate key. how should i do it?

Comment: In json parking with `Id` = 1 and =2  are "belong" to different streets? are you sure? I mean, 1 parking could be on different streets at the same time?

Comment: No, it's an error because of the set up of the relationships between the tables. ParkingId=1 belongs to StreetId 1 on CityId 1. ParkingId=2 belongs to StreetId 2 on CityId1. i don't know how to correct this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your classes. First of all I renamed them to a singular form. Then I removed the unnecessary parking from city as you get the city based on the street and lastly I added a missing relation street-parking:

```
  public class Parking
        {
            [Key]
            public int ParkId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string EndDate { get; set; 

            public int StreetId { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("StreetId")]
            public virtual Street Street { get; set; }

        }


        public class City
        {
            [Key]
            public int CityId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string CityDesc { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Street> Street { get; set; }

         }

        public class Street
        {
            [Key]
            public int StreetId { get; set; }

            public int CityId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string StreetDesc { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("CityId")]
            public virtual City City { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Parking> Parking { get; set; }

        }
```

I wrote this with my mobile, so I might have missed something reading or writing, but hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but what if i got to have a CityId column in Parkings db?
the whole problem is that i am not able to work with both of them in the Parkings db

Comment: You could get `CityId` by `var parking = dbContext.Parkings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParkId == someParkId); if (parking != null) { cityId = parking.Street.CityId; }`

Comment: Even more simple: `var cityId = db.Parkings.Where(p => p.ParkId == someParkId).Select(p => p.Street.CityId).FirstOrDefault();`